# Find a basis for $U = \{(x, y, z)\in\mathbb R^3 : y − 3z = 0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Find a basis for $U = \{(x, y, z)\in\mathbb R^3 : y − 3z = 0\}$.

What I've started with is that this can be written as the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & -3 &| &0\end{pmatrix}$ where $y$ is a leading variable $i$ then let $y=c$ and $z=\dfrac c3$ giving me the solution = $c\left(0,1,\dfrac13\right)$, i.e., = $\mathrm{span}\left(0,1,\dfrac13\right)$ but I'm pretty sure is incorrect. Any help appreciated.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You overlooked the fact that $x$ can be anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can write $U$ as follows:

$U= \{(x,y,z) : y=3z\} = \{(x,3z,z) : x,z \in \Bbb R\} = \{ x(1,0,0) + z(0,3,1) :x,z\in \Bbb R\} = span\{(1,0,0) , (0,3,1)\}$

This last 2 vectors are clearly independent and since $dim(U) = 2$ this is a basis for $U$.